# Не получается разобрать многомерный массив

Tags: php

Есть json-строка, которую я декодирую в многомерный массив:

```
[
    {
        "@airline": "airBaltic",
        "@airline_code": "BT",
        "@title": "Из Санкт-Петербурга в Европу от 75 €! Специальное предложение от авиакомпании Air Baltic",
        "@id": "21994",
        "@href": "https://www.aviasales.ru/offers/iz-sankt-peterburga-v-evropu-ot-75-eur-spetsialnoe-predlozhenie-ot-aviakompanii-air-baltic-35f7648f-db47-41fd-a6aa-ce994621d1af",
        "@sale_date_begin": "1477526400",
        "@sale_date_end": "1477872000",
        "@flight_date_begin": "1477958400",
        "@flight_date_end": "1482105600",
        "@link": "https://hydra.aviasales.ru/adaptors/special_offer?iata=BT&utm_source=www&locale=ru&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.airbaltic.com%2Fru-ZZ%2Fcampaign%2Fbaltic-incoming-sale%3F",
        "description": [],
        "conditions": "...",
        "route": [
            {
                "@from_iata": "LED",
                "@to_iata": "TLL",
                "@from_name": "Санкт-Петербург",
                "@to_name": "Таллин",
                "@oneway_price": "от 75 €",
                "@roundtrip_price": ""
            },
            {
                "@from_iata": "LED",
                "@to_iata": "PLQ",
                "@from_name": "Санкт-Петербург",
                "@to_name": "Клайпеда",
                "@oneway_price": "от 75 €",
                "@roundtrip_price": ""
            },
            {
                "@from_iata": "LED",
                "@to_iata": "VNO",
                "@from_name": "Санкт-Петербург",
                "@to_name": "Вильнюс",
                "@oneway_price": "от 75 €",
                "@roundtrip_price": ""
            },
            {
                "@from_iata": "LED",
                "@to_iata": "RIX",
                "@from_name": "Санкт-Петербург",
                "@to_name": "Рига",
                "@oneway_price": "от 89 €",
                "@roundtrip_price": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Так вот, мне нужно обратиться к первому подмассиву `route` к элементу `from_name` и узнать его значение по ключу. По идее, у первого подмассива route должен быть индекс 0, но когда я пытаюсь к нему обратиться - получаю пустую строку.

```
<?php echo $offer['route'][0]['from_name'];?>
```

Я неправильно обращаюсь к первому массиву?

var_dump():

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (4) { ["@attributes"]=> array(10) { ["airline"]=> string(9) "airBaltic" ["airline_code"]=> string(2) "BT" ["title"]=> string(152) "Из Санкт-Петербурга в Европу от 75 €! Специальное предложение от авиакомпании Air Baltic" ["id"]=> string(5) "21994" ["href"]=> string(159) "https://www.aviasales.ru/offers/iz-sankt-peterburga-v-evropu-ot-75-eur-spetsialnoe-predlozhenie-ot-aviakompanii-air-baltic-35f7648f-db47-41fd-a6aa-ce994621d1af" ["sale_date_begin"]=> string(10) "1477526400" ["sale_date_end"]=> string(10) "1477872000" ["flight_date_begin"]=> string(10) "1477958400" ["flight_date_end"]=> string(10) "1482105600" ["link"]=> string(163) "https://hydra.aviasales.ru/adaptors/special_offer?iata=BT&utm_source=www&locale=ru&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.airbaltic.com%2Fru-ZZ%2Fcampaign%2Fbaltic-incoming-sale%3F" } ["description"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) { } ["conditions"]=> string(428) "
Цены на авиабилеты указаны с учетом топливных, аэропортовых и государственных сборов.
Количество авиабилетов на каждом рейсе по данному тарифу ограничено.
Полные условия продажи авиабилетов на сайте авиакомпании.
" ["route"]=> array(4) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(7) { ["from_iata"]=> string(3) "LED" ["to_iata"]=> string(3) "TLL" ["from_name"]=> string(29) "Санкт-Петербург" ["to_name"]=> string(12) "Таллин" ["class"]=> string(12) "эконом" ["oneway_price"]=> string(11) "от 75 €" ["roundtrip_price"]=> string(0) "" } } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(7) { ["from_iata"]=> string(3) "LED" ["to_iata"]=> string(3) "PLQ" ["from_name"]=> string(29) "Санкт-Петербург" ["to_name"]=> string(16) "Клайпеда" ["class"]=> string(12) "эконом" ["oneway_price"]=> string(11) "от 75 €" ["roundtrip_price"]=> string(0) "" } } [2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(7) { ["from_iata"]=> string(3) "LED" ["to_iata"]=> string(3) "VNO" ["from_name"]=> string(29) "Санкт-Петербург" ["to_name"]=> string(14) "Вильнюс" ["class"]=> string(12) "эконом" ["oneway_price"]=> string(11) "от 75 €" ["roundtrip_price"]=> string(0) "" } } [3]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(7) { ["from_iata"]=> string(3) "LED" ["to_iata"]=> string(3) "RIX" ["from_name"]=> string(29) "Санкт-Петербург" ["to_name"]=> string(8) "Рига" ["class"]=> string(12) "эконом" ["oneway_price"]=> string(11) "от 89 €" ["roundtrip_price"]=> string(0) "" } } } }
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос вывод `var_dump` для декодированной структуры

Comment: У вас ключ назвается не `from_name` а `@from_name`.

Comment: @Arnial он такой потому, что на самом деле конвертируется не из json, а из xml. В json я его конвертировал вручную, чтобы читателю было удобнее его читать. @ не имеет значения, потому что при конвертации в массив она удаляется в ключах.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov добавил.

Comment: На всякий случай, а как вы декодируете JSON, в ассоциативный массив (`$assoc = true`) или нет?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin нулевой элемент массива это SimpleXMLElement, и поэтому нельзя к нему обращаться как к массиву. Попробуйте `($offer['route'][0])->from_name`

Comment: @lyhoshva Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @SurfinBird прочитайте комментарий выше вашего. Я в json его декодировал вручную, чтобы вставить сюда, чтобы здешнему читателю было понятнее. xml вставлять нет смысла. Хотя, наверное, [стоило бы](http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/special-offers).

Comment: Cоветую посмотреть в сторону phpStorm + xdebug -- один раз разобравшись, сэкономите в дальнейшем много времени, как минимум видя структуру своих переменных в "реальном" времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вроде как обьект с данными:

```
$data = $offer->route[0]->attributes();
echo $data['from_name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по формату JSON всё это первый(и единственный) элемент массива, поэтому попробуйте обратиться вот так вот:

```
<?php echo $offer[0]['route'][0]['from_name'];?>
```

Comment: Не-а, не работает

Comment: `print_r($offer);` что говорит?  И посмотреть бы кусок кода от момента обращения к апи до попадания данных в $offer